# Vim keyword completion for ctags with backslashes?

Tags: php, vim, ctags

I'm using ctags for keyword completion on a PHP project in vim. Since ctags doesn't handle PHP namespaces out of the box, I've added a regex option to my ctags command:

```
ctags (...) --regex-PHP='^namespace\s+([^;]*)/\1/c/' (...)
```

This works fairly well: if I type `Foo<Ctrl+N>` I get suggestions for `Foo`, `Foo\Bar`, `Foo\Bar\Baz` and so on.

However, the backslash seems to count as a word separator when vim determines the keyword to look up in the tags file.

In other words, typing `Foo\Ba<Ctrl+N>` does *not* give me suggestions for `Foo\Bar\Baz` etc, which is what I wish. It will only suggest tags that actually start with `Ba` (i.e. none of my namespaces).

This is also an issue when jumping to a tag. If I have `Foo\Bar\Baz` under the cursor and do `Ctrl+]`, it will take me to the file containing `Baz`, which may or may not be the one containing `Foo\Bar\Baz`. If the backslash wasn't treated as a word separator, I imagine this would work much better.

So, is there a way to make vim treat the backslash as a part of the word when doing tag lookups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/php.vim` (this makes the change local to PHP files), add the following:

```
:setlocal iskeyword+=\\
```

Note that this change also affects other stuff, e.g. the `w` motion, `aw` text object, and potentially even syntax highlighting.

Comment: Thanks! Interestingly, while this works for the keyword completion, jumping to a tag with backslashes does not - it tries to find Foo\\Bar\\Baz (double backslashes), which fails.

Comment: That path probably isn't very well tested. please report this bug to the [vim_dev mailing list](http://www.vim.org/community.php).