# Special characters in tags

Tags: vim, vi

For an [API documentation project](https://github.com/mikehaertl/yii2-apidoc-vim) I have created custom help files in Vim's helptext format. I also created a `tags` files with `:helptext docs/`. The `tags` file looks like:

```
yii\base\Component::trigger yii-base-component.txt  /*yii\\base\\Component::trigger*
yii\base\Controller::$action    yii-base-controller.txt /*yii\\base\\Controller::$action*
```

While the first tag `yii\base\Component::trigger` works fine, the second one `yii\base\Controller::$action` doesn't. Vim complains that it can't find the tag.

Is there a way to make `$` characters work in tags?

And more general: Is there a better way to make vim tags play nice with namespaced classes and tags?

Comment: According to `:help tags-file-format` the only disallowed character is a tab.  If `$` does not work, I would call it a bug.

Comment: Ok, the problem is caused by the backslashes. Related topic is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712840/vim-keyword-completion-for-ctags-with-backslashes. Unfortunately there's no real acceptable solution yet.